# Matlab How to use regex on a 3 dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, regex, matlab

I have a function that is given a text file 'in' and returns a file with all 4 letter words replaced with '****.' So far I have managed to get a 3d array with each cell being 1 word. How do I turn all 4 letter words into '****?'

```
%in.txt =

     %word words
     %words words words word
     %words
     %word word word



fid = fopen(in);

tline = fgetl(fid);
string = {''};
while ischar(tline)%create an array where each cell is 1 line
    string(length(string)+1) = {tline};
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

str = {''};
for x=2:length(string)%create a matrix where each cell is is 1 line with each of those cells being 1 word
    str(x) = {split(string(x), ' ')};
    end
end
```

Comment: use `regexprep(str,'\<[a-zA-Z]{4}\>','****')`

Answer (score 1):

Use `regexprep`:

```
fid = fopen('in.txt', 'r');

% (when running in a function)
%OC = onCleanup(@() any(fopen('all')==fid) && fclose(fid));

data = regexprep(data{1}, ...
                 '\<(?:[-A-Za-z]{4})([^-A-Za-z]|$)',...
                 '****$1');            

fclose(fid);
```